# JInternalFrame snaps back to original position when cursor leaves container

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I have a JInternalFrame inside a JPanel, all is working great, but when I reposition the internal frame and then move the cursor outside the JPanel, it resets its position.

I couldn't see anything in the API related to this.

Comment: Seems your internal frame is no longer scared by the mousepointer, hence he jumps back to his favourite position ^-^ (Sorry, could not help myself laughing ;D your problem seems very strange, never saw/heard something like this)

Comment: Please post an SSCCE, this is not normal, there must be something else going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a JInternalFrame inside a JPanel,

An internal frame was not designed to be used with a JPanel.

It was designed to be used with a JDesktopPane which uses a null layout. A JPanel uses a FlowLayout by default.

So I would guess somehow the layout manager is invoked and the location of the internal frame is being reset.

Just use a desktop pane and you won't have these problems.

Comment: This sounds very plausible, I will try! Thanks

Comment: This was the problem. I set my JPanel's layout to null and everything works as expected. Thanks